# Não consigo colocar o .value no codigo JavaScript fica dando erro

Tags: javascript

````
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form" action="" method="get">
        <p>Name:<input type="text" class="name"></p>
        <p>Sobrenome:<input type="text" class="sobrenome"></p>
        <p>Peso:<input type="text" class="peso"></p>
        <p>Altura:<input type="text" class="altura"></p>
        <button>Enviar</button>

        <div class="resultado"></div>

    </form>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>```
````

function meuEscopo(){
const form = document.querySelector(".form");
const resultado = document.querySelector(".resultado");

```
const pessoas = [];

function recebeEventoForm(evento){
    evento.preventDefault(); 
    const nome = form.querySelector(".nome");
    const sobrenome = form.querySelector(".sobrenome");
    const peso = form.querySelector(".peso");
    const altura = form.querySelector(".altura");

    pessoas.push({
        nome: nome.value,
        sobrenome: sobrenome.value,
        peso: peso.value,
        altura: altura.value
    });
    console.log(pessoas);

    resultado.innethtml += `<p>${nome.value} ${sobrenome.value} ${peso.value} ${altura.value}</p>`
 };

 form.addEventListener("submit", recebeEventoForm);
```

}

meuEscopo();

```
quero que salve no document a cada vez que escrever os dados e clicar no botao de enviar, porém da erro no value.
```

Comment: Para prosseguir dentro do objetivo do site é importante [edit] sua postagem removendo o código atual e em vez dele postar um [mcve] do problema e, se possível, uma descrição melhor da dificuldade em resolver. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> const nome = form.querySelector(".nome");
>
> Name:

Classe HTML contem o "name", e você usou o "nome" no javascript.
Mudança seria->

```
const pessoas = [];

function recebeEventoForm(evento){
    evento.preventDefault(); 
    const nome = form.querySelector(".name");
    const sobrenome = form.querySelector(".sobrenome");
    const peso = form.querySelector(".peso");
    const altura = form.querySelector(".altura");

    pessoas.push({
        nome: nome.value,
        sobrenome: sobrenome.value,
        peso: peso.value,
        altura: altura.value
    });
    console.log(pessoas);

    resultado.innethtml += `<p>${nome.value} ${sobrenome.value} ${peso.value} ${altura.value}</p>`
 };

 form.addEventListener("submit", recebeEventoForm);
```